# How to load javascript in CakePHP?

Tags: javascript, cakephp, bxslider

I'm fresh in CakePHP, current work in a website which a part require bxsldier. 
I imported scripts with following code:

```
echo $this->Html->script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js');
    echo $this->Html->script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate- 1.1.1.min.js');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.9.0.min');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery');
    echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery.nivo.slider');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery.bxslider');
    echo $this->Html->script('site');
```

Scripts:
$(document).ready(function(){

> ```
>       $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
>             minSlides: 1,
>             maxSlides: 4,
>             slideWidth: 239,
>             slideMargin: 0,
>             pager: false
>       });
>                     });
> ```

and the HTML:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
          <li>
            <div class="bxImg">
                <?php echo $this->Html->image('test-pic.png'); ?>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>"</span>Porttitor pulvinar, odio, voluptatem  laboriosam, ornare, eius ab neque saepe, platea aut dolore, mus. Eligendi aliquip!
            </div>
            <div class="bxPerson">
                By Thomas Longbottom
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="bxImg">
                <?php echo $this->Html->image('test-pic.png'); ?>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>"</span>Porttitor pulvinar, odio, voluptatem laboriosam, ornare, eius ab neque saepe, platea aut dolore, mus. Eligendi aliquip!
            </div>
            <div class="bxPerson">
                By Thomas Longbottom
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="bxImg">
                <?php echo $this->Html->image('test-pic.png'); ?>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>"</span>Porttitor pulvinar, odio, voluptatem laboriosam, ornare, eius ab neque saepe, platea aut dolore, mus. Eligendi aliquip!
            </div>
            <div class="bxPerson">
                By Thomas Longbottom
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="bxImg">
                <?php echo $this->Html->image('test-pic.png'); ?>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>"</span>Porttitor pulvinar, odio, voluptatem laboriosam, ornare, eius ab neque saepe, platea aut dolore, mus. Eligendi aliquip!
            </div>
            <div class="bxPerson">
                By Thomas Longbottom
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="bxImg">
                <?php echo $this->Html->image('test-pic.png'); ?>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>"</span>Porttitor pulvinar, odio, voluptatem laboriosam, ornare, eius ab neque saepe, platea aut dolore, mus. Eligendi aliquip!
            </div>
            <div class="bxPerson">
                By Thomas Longbottom
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="bxImg">
                <?php echo $this->Html->image('test-pic.png'); ?>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>"</span>Porttitor pulvinar, odio, voluptatem laboriosam, ornare, eius ab neque saepe, platea aut dolore, mus. Eligendi aliquip!
            </div>
            <div class="bxPerson">
                By Thomas Longbottom
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

And the result comes with content loaded but script not running.
Anysuggestion on how to make it run?

Answer (score 1):

First thing to fix is the following:

```
echo $this->Html->script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate- 1.1.1.min.js');
```

It has a space after 'migrate' and it shouldn't be. You should have the following instead:

```
echo $this->Html->script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js');
```

Also, I noticed you are using multiple versions of jQuery. I would use only one, perhaps the most current one. If none of those help, post back and we can try to help further.

Comment: @a_santiago Hi, I'm sorry it's was a typo ><
I checked the script it was alright, I tried using only these 3 js
-jquery-1.9.0-min.js
-jquery.bxslider.js
-site.js

And it still gave me the same result.

Comment: Hey, did you test if jQuery runs without problems by having something like `<script>$(document).ready(function(){alert("jQuery Test");});</script>` somewhere in your document?

Comment: ya, I using a layout to control all the pages view.
The jquery works in every pages.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Kooki3 i have seen your question there is some mistake in your program.

First:

```
echo $this->Html->script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js');
echo $this->Html->script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate- 1.1.1.min.js');
echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.9.0.min');
```

Solution- Please use atleast one jquery min file. If you put  more than one jquery min file it will be conflicted your jquery.

Second:

Give the right link on your jquery min file.

```
echo $this->Html->script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate- 1.1.1.min.js');
```

Solution- Remove space after "migrate-"

Use`echo $this->Html->script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js');`

don't use more than one jquery min file in one single project.

Always use latest jquery min file.
http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: Hi, I downloaded the latest jQuery which is v1.10.1 (not min)
and use with only jquery.bxslider.js and the jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.
Still the same result.